# What's the point of using LiveData in ViewModel if I can use Flow and StateFlow with lifecycleScope \ viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines

`Flow` has a lot of operators, `LiveData` has only 3 (Transformations). Is there any reason to keep using LiveData <strike>except StateFlow is still experimental</strike>?

UPD. StateFlow, SharedFlow and corresponding operators are promoted to stable API in kotlinx.coroutines 1.4.0

Comment: You can build any transformation you want for a LiveData, you just have to use the `MediatorLiveData` to do it. Internally, all "pre-made" transformations rely on MediatorLiveData, too.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, i know, but should i reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Depends, is it difficult? Is the end result reliable? I have a [library for combining multiple LiveDatas](https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combinetuple-kt/blob/master/livedata-combinetuple-kt/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/livedatacombinetuplekt/LiveDataCombineTuple.kt) and I didn't find it particularly hard to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not much reason to use LiveData nowadays. (State)Flow/Coroutines also brings new possibilites via lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated/Started/Resumed, hard to do with LiveData.

But there is one reason when LiveData is needed - DataBinding. It currently doesn't support observing Flow.

EDIT: there is going to be support for StateFlow in DataBinding in Android  Studio 4.3: https://twitter.com/manuelvicnt/status/1314621067831521282

Comment: Guess you could always just call `.asLiveData()` on your Flow in the data binding case.

Comment: unfortunately this is not helping with two way data-binding

Comment: keep in mind the main reason for `LiveData`'s existence is its compatibility with Android lifecycles. Still now, `Flow` doesn't handle these correctly and you can find warnings all throughout its documentation about this.